# getPosition Deprecated What should I use instead?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I am creating an `onTouchListener` for a `RecyclerView` item and `getPosition()` is deprecated in the code below, what can I use as a substitute?

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context,NavigateTo.class));
        if(clicklistener!=null)
        {
            clicklistener.itemClickd(v,getPosition());
        }


    }
```

Comment: Whenever something is deprecated, you should consult [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getPosition()) for recommendations.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try `getLayoutPosition()`

> **This method is deprecated.**
>
> This method is deprecated because its
> meaning is ambiguous due to the async handling of adapter updates.
> Please use getLayoutPosition() or getAdapterPosition() depending on
> your use case.

See Also

> [getLayoutPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getLayoutPosition())
>
> [getAdapterPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition())

Comment: Thanks man, your answer helped me! @Eli why not select this as the best answer?